# Не загружаются иконки из QtDesigner в PyQt6

Tags: qt-designer, pyqt6

Решил переписать код с PyQt5 на PyQt6, все работает, но иконок кнопок я не обнаружил. Как мне получить иконки, которые я выставлял в прошлой версии? На ней, кстати, все работало. Кнопки тоже работают, но не отображают иконок. Если надо что-то ещё прикрепить, напишите и я постараюсь прикрепить. Заранее спасибо.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSizeGrip, QFileDialog
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt6 import uic, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
import png_icons
import sys
import os


GLOBAL_STATE = 0
count = 0


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dragPos = None
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('MP3Player6.ui', self)
        self.ui.position = 0
        # Size Grip
        self.size_grip = QSizeGrip(self.ui.f_status_right)
        self.size_grip.setToolTip("Resize Window")
        self.size_grip.setStyleSheet("QSizeGrip "
                                    "{ width: 20px; height: 20px; margin: 5px } "
                                    "QSizeGrip:hover "
                                    "{ background-color: none; }")
        # Title bar
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Buttons
        self.ui.btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.ui.btn_hide.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())
        self.ui.btn_maximize.clicked.connect(lambda: self.window_size())
        # Player
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.audio_output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput()

        self.load_files()

        def move_window(event):
            if GLOBAL_STATE == 1:
                self.window_size()
            if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
                pos = self.pos()
                glpos = event.globalPosition().toPoint()
                self.move(pos + glpos - self.dragPos.toPoint())
                self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()
                event.accept()
        self.ui.f_title.mouseMoveEvent = move_window

        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()

    def window_size(self):
        global GLOBAL_STATE
        status = GLOBAL_STATE
        if status == 0:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.ui.main_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color:'
                                             ' qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(42, 44, 111, 255), stop:0.522727 rgba(28, 29, 73, 255));'
                                             ' border-radius: 0px')
            GLOBAL_STATE = 1
        else:
            self.showNormal()
            self.ui.main_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color:'
                                             ' qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(42, 44, 111, 255), stop:0.522727 rgba(28, 29, 73, 255));'
                                             ' border-radius: 15px;')
            GLOBAL_STATE = 0

    def load_files(self):
        spisok = []
        for file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Michael\Мусор\Music"):
            if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                spisok.append(file)
                self.ui.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setPointSize(20)
                self.ui.btn.setFont(font)
                self.ui.path = r'C:\Users\Michael\Мусор\Music\\' + str(file)
                self.ui.btn.setText(self.ui.path)
                self.ui.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.ui.path)
                self.ui.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.ui.btn)
                self.ui.btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, g=self.ui.url: self.play_mp3_file(g))

    def play_mp3_file(self, g):
        self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio_output)
        self.player.setSource(g)
        self.audio_output.setVolume(50)
        self.player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

1. Я перегенерировал старый ui файл в новом QtDesignere(Из qt6-applications), сохранив его в MP3Player6.ui(Это не помогло):

```
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('MP3Player6.ui', self)
```

2. Я подумал, что проблема в файле png_icons.py(Который я получил, преобразовав png_icons.qrc еще в PyQt5), поэтому попытался преобразовать png_icons.qrc в аналог png_icons.py на PyQt6. Так и не нашел способ это сделать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099225/how-can-resources-be-provided-in-pyqt6-which-has-no-pyrcc

Comment: Я смог преобразовать qrc файл в py на версии PyQt6, теперь иконки показываются в файле ui, преобразованном в py, но как мне использовать его для загрузки через uic.loadUi('MP3Player6.ui', self) в о основной скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена: я преобразовал qrc файл с помощью `pyside6-rcc png_icons6.qrc -o png_icons6.py` (Установив до этого PySide6) и импортировал png_icons6 в главный файл